# Can File.Delete cause a folder to open in Windows Explorer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, explorer

I have a very strange problem where at a certain point of my application, Windows Explorer seems to just open a folder by itself.

It doesn't happen if I step through with the visual studio Debugger, but through strategically setting breakpoints, it appears to be happening in this area on the `File.Delete` line. I got this by setting a break before the line (it doesn't happen) and trying again setting the break after the line (it does)

```
public static void RestoreIniFile()
{
    string strIniPath = RetrieveIniPath(); // This method figures just assigns a value to the string based on a registry setting. 

    if (File.Exists(strIniPath + "pdf995.ini_backup"))
    {
        if (File.Exists(strIniPath + "pdf995.ini"))
        {
            File.Delete(strIniPath + "pdf995.ini");
        }

        File.Move(strIniPath + "pdf995.ini_backup", strIniPath + "pdf995.ini");

    }

}
```

`strIniPath` has the value of `C:\pdf995\res` but the directory being opened is `C:\pdf995\res\convert`

When I remove the code above, it stops happening, but it doesn't start happening again if I put the code back in! (I have to uninstall and reinstall the application to make it start happening again). The code above is called from two separate locations while executing, about 1-2 seconds apart, and this happens on the second run through.

I can also prevent it by putting in a few `Thread.Sleep` lines amongst the code, however I don't really want this as a solution as it doesn't get to the root of the problem and is also quite inefficient (the delay has to be around half a second or more).

Note that a PDF995 report is generated between the two calls (this is what causes the existing delay) so perhaps someone with knowledge of that application could shed some light? Perhaps deleting the ini file causes PDF995 to open this folder for some reason?

Alternatively, is there a way of getting info about what caused an application to be launched either in Windows itself or Visual Studio?

**Edit**

Here is the code in `RetrieveIniPath()`. It doesn't hit the `catch` section.

```
public static string RetrieveIniPath()
{
    string strPdf995IniPath = "";

    try
    {
        string regPath = Consts.PDF995_PATH;

        RegistryKey regKey = null;
        regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(regPath);

        strPdf995IniPath = (String)regKey.GetValue("UninstallString", string.Empty);

        if (strPdf995IniPath.Contains("setup.exe"))
        {
            strPdf995IniPath = strPdf995IniPath.Substring(0, strPdf995IniPath.IndexOf("setup.exe")) + "res\\";
        }
        else
        {
            strPdf995IniPath = (String)regKey.GetValue("DisplayIcon", string.Empty);

            if (strPdf995IniPath.Length > 10)
            {
                strPdf995IniPath = strPdf995IniPath.Substring(0, strPdf995IniPath.Length - 9) + "res\\";
            }
            else
            {
                strPdf995IniPath = @"c:\pdf995\res\";
            }
        }
        regKey.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogManager.Instance().LogError(ex.Message, true);
    }

    if (strPdf995IniPath.Length == 0)
    {
        strPdf995IniPath = @"c:\pdf995\res\";
    }

    return strPdf995IniPath;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you have another thread that change `strIniPath`. Can you add a log with `strIniPath` in runtime before you delete?

Comment: @Ygalbel - `strIniPath` is a local variable in this method (I've updated the question to illustrate), in any case I have checked the value of it through watches and Console.WriteLines and it does indeed have the value I assume (`C:\pdf995\res`)

Comment: `File.Delete` doesn't open anything. It doesn't have anything to do with the shell and Explorer to begin with. That's it. Do you use `Process.Start` anywhere in your code? If you pass a folder path as the executeable, Explorer will open the folder

Comment: But you said that doesn't reproduce in debug. That will help you to see the value when you don't stop the code.

Comment: @Ygalbel - It does happen in debug, it doesn't happen when I *step* in Debug. Besides, as I said in the comment, I've used `Console.WriteLine` which gives the same value.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't have the window open already in the background? If a file disappeared perhaps it just brought the window to the foreground. Is the folder left open as part of the installation process?

Comment: @colmde the code you posted here doesn't do anything with the *folder* anyway, just individual paths. What does `RetrieveIniPath` do? If `Thread.Sleep` doesn't display the folder, it probably means you have threading issues with something that *does* open a folder

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - (Re: your first comment) I know. That's what has me so puzzled! There is no `Process.Start`

Comment: @colmde you haven't posted anything that can reproduce the problem yet. There's no point in looking for problems with File.Delete. Something else causes the problem. Something that reacts to deletes. A FileSystemWatcher perhaps, that does open the folder? Or, as John Wu said, the folder was already open?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos (Re: your second comment). `RetrieveIniPath()` looks in the registry and does some string manipulation with the value that's retrieved from there.

Comment: Also the folder was definitely not already open, I have tried, and shook my head at this many times!

Comment: @colmde post that code. You're asking for help but the code you posted doesn't demonstrate the problem. It's not `File.Delete`, *that's* a certainty. Extraordinary claims require extraordinary proof as they say

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - as requested I've posted the code of the other method. It *is* happening on `File.Delete`! (whether directly or indirectly) If I set a breakpoint immeadiately after this line, the folder opens. If I set a breakpoint on this line (so the line doesn't get to execute), it doesn't. My current working theory is that PDF995 doesn't like having it's ini file being deleted and is opening the folder in response for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I've concluded that it's the PDF995 module itself (`pdfsave` process) that's opening the folder in response to its ini file being deleted. It does this also if the file is overwritten so changing to the `Move` to a `Copy` (with overwrite) didn't help. The process hadn't completely closed by the time execution of my application reached the `File.Delete`.

My solution is simply to wait for the process to exit before replacing the file.

```
while (true)
{
    Process[] pdfProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("pdfsave");
    if (pdfProcess.Length == 0)
    {
        break;
    }

    Thread.Sleep(50);
}

if (File.Exists(strIniPath + "pdf995.ini"))
{
    File.Delete(strIniPath + "pdf995.ini");
}

File.Move(strIniPath + "pdf995.ini_backup", strIniPath + "pdf995.ini");
```

Why removing, then restoring the code caused it to stop happening remains a mystery...